# How to create array and display required array value

Tags: arrays, vbscript, qtp

how to create array and display required array value. For example:

Arr[0]="anand" Arr[1]="bala".print Arr optin:2, Bala .

i need the required array output

Comment: Did you even bother to search first?

Answer (score 0):

Queat seems a bit unclear.
May be below piece of code can be relevent to your Question.

```
'Initializing & Filling up array
Dim testArr(3)
testArr(0)="First"
testArr(1)="Second"
testArr(2)="Third"

Dim Iterator,userInput

'If you Need ro validate the User input you need to use Err Object.
'Like if it's number or not/Is teh User Provided value is positive or not/ etc. etc. which i'm not doing now)

userInput=Cint(inputbox("Please enter a Positive number between 1-" & Ubound(testArr)))

If userInput<=Ubound(testArr) Then
   MsgBox(testArr(userInput-1))
Else
    MsgBox("Wrong Value Provided. Not Applicable Array Index Number !!!")
End If
```